# Bypass 30 days limit

Tags: internal-storage, gallery

I downloaded some comics from Line Webtoons and they were stored in android>data>com.naver.webtoons>files.
But when i copied the .jpg files they were unable to view also in photo viewer it said

> could not load image

I read that all files will expire after 30 days. Can anyone tell me how to bypass this so that i can view images in image viewer otherwise i will have to download them again.

Comment: I Am Not A Lawyer, but I recommend you to follow their policy of 30-day. There must be a reason why Line does that (make sense, or not), but personally, I won't encourage to breach that policy for whatever reasons.

Comment: Dude i dont wanna bypass tge app i just want to be able to view the images separately using any image viewer.

Comment: Apparently, the question title and the body gives that feeling. Mind to [edit] and make it clear what you really want? Please be specific.